# Add object to QListWidget

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I have a class

```
class MyClass
 {
  public:
  QString name;
  int age;
 };
...
MyClass* itm1= new MyClass();
itm1->name="John";
itm1->age=20;
```

I want to add itm1 to QListWidget that will display `itm1->name` and when I doubleclick the item in the list to show me `itm1->age` in a messagebox.
Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```cpp
QListWidget* listWidget = new QListWidget();
connect(listwidget, SIGNAL (itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), yourClass, SLOT(itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem*)));

MyClass* itm1= new MyClass();
itm1->name="John";
itm1->age=20;

QListWidgetItem* item(itm1->name);
item->setData(Qt::UserRole, itm1->age);
listWidget->addItem(item);
```

Then just add this as a slot.

```cpp
void YourClass::itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item) {
    int age = item->data(Qt::UserRole);
    QMessageBox messageBox;
    messageBox.setText(QString::number(age));
    messageBox.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

QListWidgetItem item(itm1->name);
item.setData (Qt::UserRole, itm1);
an add that to the QListWidget.

slot: void  itemActivated ( QListWidgetItem * item ), and get your user data from the item.

Another posibility is, if you have a list of your itemas, (and it cant be changed while the click is processed), to store the index inside the userdata.
(I use the second approach in some Comboboxes in Qt4)